# I would like to know if you can import files into Hyperldeger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am new in this field and therefore I am still doing studies and researches, I would like to know if JSON files can be imported in Hyperldeger Fabric--if it is better Hyperledeger Fabric or Fabric Composer. more precisely I would like to understand if there is a way to populate the DLT of Hyperledger Fabric automatically.

for now, I have only tried Hyperledger Composer online playground

Comment: All data that goes into a Hyperledger, or any blockchain for that matter (world state and the historian) can only be done via endorsed and validated blocks. Which means the only way you can import a json is to write a function in the smart contract that accepts a json and then parses it and makes the required changes to the db. You can also write an initialization script as part of the contract.

if you have used composer playground, in the logic.js file for lot of the samples there is a `init` function that is used to prepopulate the database.

Answer (score 2):

Fabric don't have any feature to automatically populate the ledger.

You have to develop a solution in order to upoload each Json file and put that on the ledger state.

Any type of data can be inserted on the ledged because it stores byte arrays so its up to you how to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

- in case you're asking to making your chaincode or smart contract like talking to the file system and read file or even call some API to collect JSON files,
  it could be done but this will break your transaction flow specially during the endorsement process due to during the endorsement process it's expected from each peer to return the same value after executing the transaction against the chaincode to consider the transaction is a valid transaction, 
  so in case one of the endorsers failed to call the API or failed to read file from file system the transaction will considered to be invalid.
  so it's not recommended to do any third party activity in your chaincode or smart contract even if it's possible to do so.
- about populating the ledger it can be done it's eventually a database so you can dump it's data, However, if you're trying to backup to recover the ledger in case the whole network down it's impossible due to when you'll reinstall the network the whole config and certificates which were bounded to the transaction will be changed so it has no sense to do it.